# Android : cannot sent parameter to asmx web service whith Json

Tags: android, json, web-services, asmx

I try to send a complex object to asmx webservice from android using Json, I can send other complex objects and array but I'm stuck in this one, it's been a whole two days that I'm searching where is the problem without success, here is my code

```
    JSONObject param = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject item = new JSONObject();


        try {




            Date D= new Date(2012,10,10);



                    item.put("id_s", 1);
            item.put("comp", 1);
            item.put("d", D);
            item.put("duration", 1);
            item.put("la", 0.0);
            item.put("lo", 0.0);
            item.put("id_u", 1);
            item.put("id_s", 1);
            item.put("c", 1);
            item.put("i", "1");
            item.put("o", "1");
            item.put("m", "1");
            item.put("p", 2);
            param.put("s", item);


            Jsonrequest jrequest=new Jsonrequest(); 
            JSONObject result = jrequest.sendJsonRequest("192.168.125.35", 80 , 
                      "http://192.168.125.35:80/Myapp/WebService1.asmx/method", param);

        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(e1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(e), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(e), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

the weird thing is there is no exception, and I verified that the name of my parameters are the same that are in my web service.
thank you for your help.

Comment: the date? is it properly formatted? how is it transformed to json? as timestamp or as string?

Comment: the date is correctly formatted because I could send the date to the web service in the other objects, the error is that I cannot contact my web service with this parameters, nothing happens at all

Comment: you were right, the problem is in the date, but how it comes that I could send the same date format in the past :s can you indicate me please what is the correct format of the date? thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: no idea, that depends on what your WS expects. I would use either a timestamp (long) or a string representation using a format used in http headers. (there are several). Just make sure both ends agree on the format used